# Determine whether a character is a letter or number

Tags: string, go, unicode-string

Given that Go strings are unicode, is there a way to safely determine whether a character (such as the first letter in a string) is a letter or a number? In the past I would just check against ASCII character ranges, but I doubt that would be very reliable with unicode strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use [`func IsNumber(r rune) bool`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsNumber) in the `unicode` package:

```
if unicode.IsNumber(rune) { ... }
```

Just be aware that this includes more characters than just 0-9, such as roman numbers (eg. Ⅲ) or fractions (eg. ⅒) . If you specifically only want to check 0-9, you should instead do like you've done in the past (yes, it is UTF-8 safe):

```
if rune >= 48 && rune <= 57 { ... }
```

or

```
if rune >= '0' && rune <= '9' { ... } // as suggested by Martin Gallagher
```

For letters, the unicode package has a similar function: [func IsLetter(r rune) bool](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsLetter)

Comment: Note, for ASCII, to improve clarity you can also use: `if rune >= '0' && rune <= '9' { ... }`

Comment: @MartinGallagher True. Produces equivalent executable, but your suggestion makes the code a bit more clear. I added it in an edit.